# Extjs 4 store sync issue

Tags: php, extjs, extjs4

I have the following code:

> The Store :

```
Ext.define('strClientesRECO', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'mdlClientesRECO',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        pageParam: undefined,
        startParam: undefined,
        limitParam: undefined,
        api: {
            read: 'some url',
            create: 'some url',
            update: 'some url',
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },

        writer: {
            root: 'records',
            encode: true,
            writeAllFields: false
        }
    }
});
```

---

> The grid has the following properties:

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
selType: 'cellmodel',
plugins: [{
   ptype: 'cellediting',
   clicksToEdit: 2
}],
```

---

> In the controller I have a listener to sync the store every cell update

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewGridClientesRECO')[0].getStore().addListener('update', this.onUpdateRecords, this);
onUpdateRecords: function() {
    var storeGridClientes = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewGridClientesRECO')[0].getStore();
    storeGridClientes.sync();
},
```

But in the PHP file that is executed when I update, if I print `$_POST` the records sends are correct, but it never sends the *id* of the edited row.

Comment: While sending records from server are you sending the ids ? Verify it by adding a column with dataIndex: 'id'

Comment: Ok,in my model id was "Id",and upper I in id doesn´t work,I have change it to lower i and send the id correctly,thanks.

Comment: @SensacionRC if you want your field to be "Id" instead of "id", use configure "idProperty" of you model.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty